# What is the API used, to know the Volume status in pocket pc 2003 environment using c++?

Tags: c++, windows, volume, pocketpc, mute

What is the API used to know whether the volume is mute or not in Pocket PC 2003 environment using c++?

To set volume, I have used the following API:-

```
waveOutSetVolume(0,volume[volumeStatus.volume]);
```

And to get volume, I have used the following API:-

```
waveOutGetVolume(0, (LPDWORD)&volume);
```

Please let me know what is the API for setting and getting Mute status?

Comment: Could anyone tell me please that what is the api used for the above?

Comment: Get the volume and check if it's zero?

Comment: In Pocket PC 2003 environement, The MIXERLINE concepts for getting & setting the mute status is not working. Also i am not able to set and get the volume level using MIXERLINE concepts. So i am using waveoutgetvolume & waveoutsetvolume api in pocketpc 2003 environment.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg: I dont need volume level, we can get volume level by waveoutgetvolume but we will not get mute status. I mean to say whether mute is checked or not. For this, there must be some API which can check the mute status.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution for the above:

***Method to Get Mute status:***

```
    void vGetMuteStatus(){
    LONG lReturn; 
        HKEY hkey; 
        DWORD dwLen, dwMode;     
        lReturn = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER,
                    L"ControlPanel\\Notifications\\ShellOverrides",
                    0,KEY_QUERY_VALUE|KEY_READ,&hkey);    
        if (lReturn == ERROR_SUCCESS)    {       
            dwLen = sizeof(DWORD);       
            lReturn = RegQueryValueEx(hkey,L"Mode", NULL, NULL,
                               (LPBYTE)&dwMode, &dwLen);       
            RegCloseKey(hkey);    
        } 
        if(dwMode == 2)
            MSGBOX(NULL,L"Volume",L"Volume is Mute",MB_OK);
        else
            MSGBOX(NULL,L"Volume",L"Volume is not Mute",MB_OK);
}
```